# Get number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC in apex

Tags: apex, datetime

I want the apex equivalent of the following javascript method :

```
 var utcDate3 = Date.UTC(2019, 7, 19, 18, 20, 5);
```

Because I need the number of milliseconds in the given Date object since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, universal time, but implemented in apex.

Comment: I'm curious as to what research you did prior to asking this question.

Comment: Ditto. But it was a 30sec answer, so I helped out.

Comment: I check documentation on datetime methods, and there is no in-built method to get time elapsed from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC in apex

Comment: I've downvoted this for lack of research, because searching for any of "January", "milliseconds", "1970" in the datetime documentation would have quickly turned up the answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted in my answer? Salesforce has a native method to do exactly that.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_methods_system_datetime

Comment: Yeah...the documentation which describes what this method does matches almost verbatim what is in your post. Lack of research effort. -1

Comment: The answer to the question is clearly stated in the documentation

Answer (score 6):

Per [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_methods_system_datetime) document, you can use get the `getTime()` method for this.

> **getTime()**
>    Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this DateTime object.

In your case,

```
DateTime utcDate3 = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2019, 7, 19, 18, 20, 5);
Long myMiliseconds = utcDate3.getTime();
```

Comment: It gives error in JSconsole.

Comment: OP wanted Apex, not JS. :D

Comment: ` var utcDate3 = Date.UTC(2019, 7, 19, 18, 20, 5);`  is javascript syntax, crap

Comment: yups.. I misread